# How to get excel hyperlink in c# code object?

Tags: c#, excel, smtp

I have an excel sheet that has a paragraph with some random hyperlink but when I read excel in c# code I lost hyperlink.

I tried getting a link using excel hyperlink class and tried replacing in-text coming from excel but not working.

I have to read paragraphs along with hyperlinks and send HTML mail along with the same hyperlink.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please, put the code so we can have a reference on the libraries and types you're using. Excel can be read from c# from many ways.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess due to the lack of specific details in your posting. But if the "paragraph" is a long string and the hyperlink is imbedded in it, you can't interpret the entire paragraph as a link, it won't resolve. You probably need to isolate the hyperlink and extract it from the paragraph before you can interpret it.